# MySQL select from database where not in

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to clean records from one database according to that if they not exists in other.
It's fairly hard to explain it so here is example:

```
Table Users
-----------
id
username
password

Table Articles
--------------
id
title
created_by
edited_by
```

`created_by` and `deleted_by` contain the user ID.
I have 3-4 tables with almost the same structure like the articles table and I want to delete users from table users who don't have any record in articles-like tables.
I mean users whos ID cannot be found in any of the articles-like tables in the `created_by` and `edited_by` table.
How to do that?
I first tried to see if I can select all the data by all the tables according to users, but  the server cannot execute the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
JOIN `articles` 
ON `articles`.`created_by` = `users`.`id`  
AND `articles`.`edited_by` = `users`.`id` 
JOIN `articles_two` 
ON `articles_two`.`created_by` = `users`.`id` 
AND `articles_two`.`edited_by` = `users`.`id` 
JOIN `articles_three` 
ON `articles_three`.`created_by` = `users`.`id` 
AND `articles_three`.`edited_by` = `users`.`id` 
JOIN `articles_four` 
ON `articles_four`.`created_by` = `users`.`id` 
AND `articles_four`.`edited_by` = `users`.`id` 
JOIN `articles_five` 
ON `articles_five`.`created_by` = `users`.`id` 
AND `articles_five`.`edited_by` = `users`.`id` 
JOIN `articles_six` 
ON `articles_six`.`created_by` = `users`.`id` 
AND `articles_six`.`edited_by` = `users`.`id`;
```

Comment: creator and editor should have always same `id`?

Comment: Anytime you see tables called something_1, something_2, etc... alarm bells should start to ring. You may need to amend your schema design. In the short term, you should use UNION to "merge" (the relevant columns from) those tables into one.

Comment: `created_by` and `edited_by` may differ that gets the things harder. The database design is really terrible, but I cannot make changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is `not in` in the `select` clause:

```
select *
from users u
where u.id not in (select created_by from articles where created_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select edited_by from articles where edited_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select created_by from articles_two where created_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select edited_by from articles_two where edited_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select created_by from articles_three where created_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select edited_by from articles_three where edited_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select created_by from articles_four where created_by is not null) and
      u.id not in (select edited_by from articles_four where edited_by is not null)
```

Performance should be helped by having indexes on the various `created_by` and `edited_by` columns.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's not terribly elegant but I think it's easy to follow:

```
DELETE FROM Users
WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT Created_By FROM Articles
  UNION SELECT Edited_By FROM Articles
  UNION SELECT Created_By FROM Articles_Two
  UNION SELECT Edited_By FROM Articles_Two
  ...
  UNION SELECT Created_By FROM Articles_Six
  UNION SELECT Edited_By FROM Articles_Six
)
```

As with any big "cleanup" query, (a) make a copy of the table first and (b) review carefully before typing `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `left outer join ... where null` tends to perform better than `in` or `exists` (where there are appropriate indexes), so the following should be worth trying:

```
SELECT u.* FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `articles` ac1 ON ac1.`created_by` = u.`id`  
LEFT JOIN `articles_two` ac2 ON ac2.`created_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_three` ac3 ON ac3.`created_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_four` ac4 ON ac4.`created_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_five` ac5 ON ac5.`created_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_six` ac6 ON ac6.`created_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles` ae1 ON ae1.`edited_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_two` ae2 ON ae2.`edited_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_three` ae3 ON ae3.`edited_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_four` ae4 ON ae4.`edited_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_five` ae5 ON ae5.`edited_by` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `articles_six` ae6 ON ae6.`edited_by` = u.`id`
WHERE COALESCE(ac1.`created_by`,ac2.`created_by`,ac3.`created_by`,
               ac4.`created_by`,ac5.`created_by`,ac6.`created_by`,
               ae1.`edited_by`, ae2.`edited_by`, ae3.`edited_by`, 
               ae4.`edited_by`, ae5.`edited_by`, ae6.`edited_by`)
IS NULL;
```